# Best process to reset a bbpress forum into blog

Tags: reset

Hello Dear Reader :) ,

I have a site providing tutorials that has been set up a long time ago as a forum with bbpress.

I do realize that :

- the forum setup is not optimal
- the site has "a long life" thus is bloated with leftovers of numerous themes & plugins that have been deleted long ago
- it had a fair frequentation, but is really heading down

Thus I want to revive it with a modern theme, as a blog, with the same domain name and with it's existing SEO juice (thus permalinks).

My question is : what will be the best process to do this ?

I wonder if creating a staging (with softaculous), creating the new blog on the staging while adding the best tutorials then moving the forum on a subdirectory and shifting the staging on the main domain is the good path ?

Is that clear enough ?
What would you suggest ?

Best